# Prove $A=\{x\in (1,2): \text{the decimal expansion of $x$ contains only } 1,3 \text{ or }5\}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove $A=\{x\in (1,2): \text{the decimal expansion of $x$ contains only}~ 1,~3~\text{or}~5\}$ is compact

It is bounded being a subset of $(1,2)$ the only thing left to prove is that it is closed. One way I am trying to prove is that if $x$ is not in $A$ then it cannot be its limit point so that $A$ contains all its limit point and thus is closed.

Comment: What does the restriction mean, exactly? It contains the substring "135"? It contains only 1, 3, or 5? It contains at least one 1, 3, or 5?

Comment: Your strategy is sound.

Comment: Your strategy sounds good. Another approach would be to write it as a countable intersection of closed sets, where you begin with an appropriate *closed* interval and recursively delete certain open tenths of each subinterval at each step. Then since an intersection of closed sets is closed and the complement of an open set is closed, the result is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all numbers whose $n$th decimal digit (i.e. just one digit, not *all* digits) is $2$, $3$, or $5$ is closed.  Prove that first.

Then look at the intersection over all values of $n$ and use the fact that an intersection of any set of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my second answer, somewhat closer to what is suggested in the question.  Suppose one of the digits, say the $n$th, is *not* $2$, $3$, or $5$.  Let's say it's $4$.  A concrete example:
$$
x=0.2253525554.
$$
This number is within the open interval
$$
(0.225352555, 0.2253525556)
$$
The decimal expansion of every number in that interval requires digits other than $2$, $3$, or $5$.  So $x$ is in an open interval not intersecting the set we're concerned with, so $x$ cannot be a limit point of that set.

Your next task may perhaps be to write this argument abstractly.